# Accidentally redefined int64 in F# interactive

Tags: f#

Maybe I'm missing something obvious. In the F# interpreter, some things works as I expect:

```
> 10;;
val it : int = 10
> int 10;;
val it : int = 10
> 10L;;
val it : int64 = 10L
```

However, some things do not. I would expect the following to return int64, not int, and I would not expect 10 to be converted to 0.

```
> int64 10;;
val it : int = 0
> int64;;
val it : ('a -> int) = <fun:clo@143-3>
```

How do I convert an integer to an int64?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible you've accidentally redefine int64? Something like `let inline int64 = int`. When I try I get the expected result:

```
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.40219.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> int64 20;;
val it : int64 = 20L
> int64;;
val it : (int -> int64) = <fun:it@2>
>
```

Comment: doh, you're right. I will accept the answer when the site lets me, apparently you are not allowed to instantly accept.